# How to print out a random String from an array in Java

Tags: arrays, string, random

Hi I have been trying to make my first game for a while but have run into difficulty. I want to pull a randomized String from an array of Strings and then print it out but I have errors in my code. I have looked all over but I can't find the solution. Here is the code:
(I have already declared the currentRoom varible)

```
      int currentRoom;
String [][] rooms = {{"Start", "Treasure Room1"}, {"Goblin Home1", "Spider Nest1"}};

Random rand = new Random()
currentRoom = rooms [rand.nextInt( rooms.length)];


System.out.println(currentRoom);
```

I have an error on my currentRoom variable in line 6 and I think that is messing everything up, but I don't know so the mistake could be anywhere.

Any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you have to change:

1. currentRoom should be String Array
2. Printing string array should be done using Arrays.toString

   ```
            String[] currentRoom;
        String [][] rooms = {{"Start", "Treasure Room1"}, {"Goblin Home1", "Spider Nest1"}};

        Random rand = new Random();

        currentRoom = rooms [rand.nextInt(rooms.length)];


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(currentRoom));
   ```

Sample Output

```
[Goblin Home1, Spider Nest1]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Because later it is going to be more complex

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a 2D array of strings?
I think you can manage with a 1D array instead.

```
String currentRoom;
String[] rooms = {"Start", "Treasure Room1", "Goblin Home1", "Spider Nest1"};
Random rand = new Random();
currentRoom = rooms [rand.nextInt( rooms.length)];

System.out.println(currentRoom);
```

Comment: Because later it is going to get more complex

Answer (score 0):

```
String currentRoom;
String [][] rooms = {{"Start", "Treasure Room1"}, {"Goblin Home1", "Spider Nest1"}};

Random rand = new Random();
int rnd = rand.nextInt( rooms.length);
currentRoom = rooms [rnd][0] + ":"+ rooms [rnd][1];

System.out.println(currentRoom);
```