# Is this code acceptable for printing out random string from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I (beginner) want to print random names (string) from an array. Although this code is working just fine, I think this is not the right way to do this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
package com.test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //print random names from the array

        String name[] = new String[10];
        name[0] = "John";
        name[1] = "James";
        name[2] = "Ashley";
        name[3] = "Robert";
        name[4] = "Bradley";
        name[5] = "Jennifer";
        name[6] = "Stewart";
        name[7] = "Natalie";
        name[8] = "Austin";
        name[9] = "Scarlette";

        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
        switch (random) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println(name[0]);
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println(name[1]);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(name[2]);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println(name[3]);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println(name[4]);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println(name[5]);
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println(name[6]);
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println(name[7]);
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println(name[8]);
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println(name[9]);
                break;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely not. Just do `System.out.println(name[random])`, you don't need the `switch` at all.

Comment: If it is working fine and you want your code reviewed.. you can check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: This question is more appropriate for the [Code Review stack exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because working code should be reviewed  in Code Review stack exchange site

Comment: Although I'm not sure the people over at *codereview* would be happy about this question either, @suraj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print out a random String from an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006449/how-to-print-out-a-random-string-from-an-array-in-java)

Comment: And remember your random range is [0,9) i.e. 9 is excluded . So use 10 instead of 9

Comment: @suraj This would be just as terrible at Code Review.

Comment: fair enough.. But it would be off topic here since it is working code..@Mast

Comment: @suraj Irrelevant, don't refer people to sites if their question isn't on-topic there either. Creates horrible messes.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post, you can delete it if you prefer (You have the "delete" link under the tags of the question)

Answer (score 11):

This would be a better way.

Remove the switch loop with

```
System.out.println(name[random]);
```

Also you can make the initialization and declaration part in a single line of code. 
[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1200621/5215474)

And whole code will become

```
package com.test;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] name = {"John","James","Ashley","Robert","Bradley","Jennifer","Stewart","Natalie","Austin","Scarlette"};
    //generating random number between 0 and name.length
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * name.length);

    //print random name from the array
    System.out.println(name[random]);

   }

}
```

Comment: You can even skip the `new String[]` part

Comment: ya added that change @AlexanderSimko

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [nextInt(int) method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) of Java's Random class.  It takes an integer as a parameter and returns a random integer that can range from 0 up to (but not including) your parameter.  This makes it perfect for accessing a random index in an array.

```
Random random = new Random()    
System.out.println(name[random.nextInt(name.length)]);
```